# Drawing outside window and updating

Tags: c#, winforms

where to put drawing code in a C# Form to make it update all the time? And how to update it, what function, what events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

override the OnPaint method, and at the end of the paint method call `Me.Invalidate()` (C#: `this.Invalidate()` )